# How to read the contents of an xml attribute's value, as a stream

Tags: c#, .net, stream, xmlreader

I have an xml document, which could be quite large.  The actual schema of the xml is very basic, but the content of one of the attributes can be very large, and I need to extract it without loading the entire document in memory.  I also need to base64 decode the attribute value.  I was planning on using CryptoStream for Base64 decoding because it can decode a stream of encoded data without loading everything thing in memory.

I've started with an XmlReader, and am able to navigate through the xml until I get to the attribute I want.

Because the crypto stream requires a source stream, and XmlReader doesn't really give me one that can read through the contents of the single attribute,  I think I need to write a stream class that can pull from the XmlReader as the stream's read method is called so that I get just the attribute value, in a stream.  What I'm wondering is, how would I read byte[] from the XmlReader, in chucks?

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(Request.Body))
{
    reader.MoveToContent();

    bool dataFound = false;         

    //find the data element
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName.Equals("data"))
        {
            bDataFound = true;
            //find the value attribute
            if (reader.MoveToAttribute("value"))
            {
                //decode the attribute value, which could be large, we need to read it a s a stream 

                var strAttributeValueStream = new XmlReaderContentStream(reader);
                var strContentDecoded = new CryptoStream(strAttributeValueStream, new FromBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Element 'data' does not have a value attribute.");
            }
        }
    }

    if (!dataFound)
    {
        throw new Exception("Element 'data' not found.");
    }
}



public class XmlReaderContentStream : Stream
{
    private XmlReader reader_m;

    public XmlReaderContentStream(XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(reader), $"Reader is null.");
        }
        reader_m = reader;
    }

    ...

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        //this would work, but it may not be base 64 encoded content.  I just want the bytes that represent the literal content.
        return reader_m.ReadContentAsBase64(buffer, offset, count);    
                
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't believe any of regular .Net Xml parsers will give you access to bytes of the attribute - all of them give you a string and there is no guarantees that underlying stream is at the start of attribute you are looking for... So if you can't live with string you'd likely need to find another parser and customize it to your needs.